# Get next midnight date and time using Python time library only

Tags: python, time

I have a timestamp generated from time.time().

Example: 1597316030
Converting to date and time this gives "Thursday, August 13, 2020 10:53:50 AM GMT+00:00".

Is it possible to get the timestamp that would correspond to "Thursday, August 14, 2020 12:00:00 AM GMT+00:00" (next midnight, or any other date and time), using only time library (without date or datetime, for example)?

Thanks!

Comment: You could attempt some crazy shenanigans with `time.mktime` but it'll be very hard to account for timezones, DST and things like julian/gregorian calendars. Is there a specific reason for not wanting to use `datetime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*using only time library (without date or datetime, for example)?*

It is possible *without* any library and quite simple after you realize that: 0 is start of epoch is midnight 1 Jan 1970 and every 24 hour is 86400 second, therefore any midnight will be multiply of 86400, thus you just need to find smallest multiply of 86400 greater than your timestamp, which can be done following way:

```
t = 1597316030
t2 = ((t//86400)+1)*86400
print(t2)
```

Output:

```
1597363200
```

Keep in mind that this solution totally ignore existence of timezones.

Comment: Timezone won't be an issue for me as I already receive my timestamp in the correct timezone.